# How can I check if the race detector is enabled at runtime?

Tags: go

Is there any way I can check if the Go program is compiled with `-race` enabled at runtime (for e.g. logging/informational purposes)?

I checked the [documentation](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector), as well as the obvious locations (`runtime/*`), but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Go 1.18 there's `debug.ReadBuildInfo()`, which provides this; for example:

```
func race() {
    b, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("could not read build info")
        return
    }

    for _, s := range b.Settings {
        if s.Key == "-race" {
            fmt.Println("-race=" + s.Value)
            return
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("-race=false")
}
```

Which will print `-race=true` or `-race=false`.

In most cases, simply using the `debug.BuildInfo.String()` method is probably the easiest, as it prints out other useful stuff as well.

Since this is available since Go 1.18, which is comparatively new at the time of writing, you may want to consider putting a `// +build go.18` build tag and provide a shim for older Go versions.

---

**Older pre-Go 1.18 answer**, kept for posterity.

As far as I can find there is no simple check for this, but when `-race` is enabled the `race` [build tag](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) is set, so you can take advantage of that.

I made a new directory `israce`, and put two files there:

`israce/race.go`:

```
// +build race

// Package israce reports if the Go race detector is enabled.
package israce

// Enabled reports if the race detector is enabled.
const Enabled = true
```

`israce/norace.go`:

```
// +build !race

// Package israce reports if the Go race detector is enabled.
package israce

// Enabled reports if the race detector is enabled.
const Enabled = false
```

Due to the build tag only one of the two files will get compiled.

This is also how the Go standard library does it ([`race.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/43f954e09858449cc5f3650720e81b7e879ab349/src/internal/race/race.go#L14), [`norace.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/43f954e09858449cc5f3650720e81b7e879ab349/src/internal/race/norace.go#L13)), but since that's an internal package it can't be imported outside of the Go source base.

Comment: `debug.BuildInfo` doesn't work for me on Go 1.21 because its `Settings` field is always an empty slice, despite passing `go test -v -race ...`