# How to set Go debug flag in vscode and know if you are running in debug

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Do you know how to set debug flag in vscode, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879070/how-can-i-see-if-the-goland-debugger-is-running-in-the-program)

 Note: the question is stated "as in C#" and for Golang(Go code)

Comment: add it to your `task.json`, it depends on your used language and compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use settings, and in my case writing go - you just set:

```
"go.buildTags": "delve",
```

And then follow the already mentioned accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879070/how-can-i-see-if-the-goland-debugger-is-running-in-the-program)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "debug flag" for an editor. For most compiled languages, a debug flag will exist if you compiled the program in debug mode.

That link you posted is a different issue. Debugger.IsAttached for c# checks for the presence of the dotnet debugger, also has nothing to do with the editor.